# Shortcut to say "if this exists in the dict, save as variable. If not, ignore" in django

Tags: django

I'm pulling in data from an external place database that returns JSON of information about locations. I'd like to save as much info as possible, but not every row has all info. I'd like to:

```
            location, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(
                name=info['name'], 
                lat=info['location']['lat'], 
                lng=info['location']['lng'], 
                address=info['location']['address'], 
            )
```

but for some locations, the address isn't present, so this would throw an error. If there a short way to do this and avoid a huge string of if .. else statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dict` method `get`

```
location, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(
                name=info['name'], 
                lat=info['location']['lat'], 
                lng=info['location']['lng'], 
                address=info['location'].get('address', None), 
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one way is to use try-except block.

```
try:
    location, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(
                name=info['name'], 
                lat=info['location']['lat'], 
                lng=info['location']['lng'], 
                address=info['location']['address'], 
            )
except:
    pass
```

Comment: But if the address wasn't present, nothing would be created right?  I still want to create the location with the info that's present.